# iOS Swift - Reference between Objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reference

I have a shared handler class in which I 'manage' objects.

In this shared class, there is a *'main object (mainObject)'* and a *'single object (singleData)'*.

If I now assign the **singleData** with the reference to **mainObject.data[index]** in **viewA** and then change **mainObject.data[index]** in **viewB**, then the singleData object also changes. How can I avoid this strong-reference here?

==> In short: I want to change the *mainObject* without changing the *singleObject*. <==

```
struct kOBJECT {
    let name: String
    let data: [Int]
}

class HandlerClass {
    
    let shared = HandlerClass()
    
    var mainObject = kOBJECT(name: "AnyName", data: [1,2,3,4,5])
    var singleData: Int?
    
}


class viewA: UIViewController {
    
    .....
    
    func didSelectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        HandlerClass.shared.singleData = HandlerClass.shared.mainObject.data[indexPath.row] // Create Reference
        viewB.indexPath = indexPath
        pushToViewController(viewB)
    }
    
}


class viewB: UIViewController {
    
    .....

    public var indexPath: IndexPath!
    
    func someFunction() {
        HandlerClass.shared.mainObject.data[indexPath.row] = 10000 // <- Does this also change the `singleData` Reference? In my case it does......
    }
    
}
```

I tried the following in *'didSelectRow'*

```
let tempValue = HandlerClass.shared.mainObject.data[indexPath.row]
HandlerClass.shared.singleObject = tempValue
```

Comment: The whole point of having a `shared`(singleton) object is to share data, if you don't want this then each view controller should have its own instance of HandlerClass

Comment: Your handler var is an instance var not a class var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand *reference* meaning. Reference works only of instances - that's a part of memory reserved for specific objects. Structs are also objects, but it works as Type (similar to Int, String, Double, Float, etc), so when you modify a `struct` as a result you will have a new object, but for class instance, you will still modify the same object as you copied only *reference* to that object.

Here example below:

```
class Apple {
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    var name: String
}

struct Pear {
    var name: String
}

var apple = Apple(name: "Apple 1")
var pear = Pear(name: "Pear 1")

var apple2 = apple // here we copy only reference
apple2.name = "Apple 2"
print(apple.name) // 1st object
print(apple2.name) // the same object

var pear2 = pear // here we create new object
pear2.name = "Pear 2"
print(pear.name) // 1st object
print(pear2.name) // 2nd object
```

Also a result (run on Playground)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that opened my eyes. The struct was just an example here, in my app I actually use a class as an object. "var apple2 = apple" How can I prevent this from creating a reference?

Comment: If you need to create new object instead of copy reference, just initiate a new instance: `var apple2 = Apple(name: apple.name)`.